# How do I change Ubuntu's GUI?

Tags: desktop-environments, appearance

Recently I installed a program to change Ubuntu's desktop but it went bad, so I uninstalled it but the GUI then had debris and stuff all around.

I had to reinstall Ubuntu completely. How do I change Ubuntu's desktop without messing up the system?

Comment: Can you add more information describing your problem? What did you change?

Answer (score 5):

We have lots of different desktops. You can (click to) install [xfce4](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/xfce4), [LXDE](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/lxde), [Gnome Shell](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/gnome-shell) (includes Gnome Panel as "fallback") or any other desktop. You choose the desktop you want to use before logging in, by clicking on the button next to the password field.