# Theme and UI changed after restart (20.04 LTS)

Tags: 20.04, themes, gui

Yesterday night I shut down my laptop, and today when I turned back it on, it's UI got changed, the bottom bar(Dock) and top bar got white and dock UI also got changed.
Also, I am not able to search for apps when I press super(windows) key, only opened apps visible to me in activities.
Here are some screenshots
[Dock Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P9DWF.png)

[Top Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZY0vc.png)

[No search option in activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lBmEK.png)

I am completely new to ubuntu please suggest me something.
[Activities](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CFkbb.png)
In activities, its theme color is blue, but my default theme is dark grey.

Output of [ls /usr/bin/*session](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2qpqM.png)

Comment: I also restarted my laptop 2-3 times but still facing this issue.

Comment: After you login open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type `ls /usr/bin/*session` and let us know what the output is. It will show what desktop you have installed. Edit your question and copy&paste the lines from the terminal output.

Comment: thanks, @darth_epoxy I was not aware of the Desktop environment, so [link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91418/how-do-i-change-ubuntus-gui) solved my problem,

Answer (score 0):

I have solved this problem by again Re-installing the Desktop environment
Here is the ref of solution
[link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91418/how-do-i-change-ubuntus-gui)